# Standard C++ equivalent for __memory_barrier

Tags: c++, multithreading, icc, lock-free, stdatomic

Is there a standard C++ equivalent for `__memory_barrier`, the "compiler fence" found in Intel's C++ compiler?

I'm under the impression that calling [`atomic_thread_fence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) with `memory_order=memory_order_acq_rel` should do the trick, is this the case?

Comment: That's overkill; if anything you want `atomic_signal_fence(mo_seq_cst)`, although some of the equivalence may only be an implementation detail, but in practice that's how compilers do it.

Comment: How about `std::barrier`?

Comment: @eerorika: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier `std::barrier` is a *thread* barrier, that waits for n threads to reach it, then allows them all to continue.  Basically nothing to do with memory barriers that order a single thread's access to coherent cache.

Comment: @PeterCordes so judging from your answer on the linked question, I should consider my assumption on `atomic_thread_fence` correct right?

Comment: No, like I commented, the equivalent is atomic **signal** fence, since you only want to prevent compile-time reordering, not runtime reordering (on weakly-ordered ISAs where runtime reordering other than StoreLoad is possible).  I double-checked and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Compile-time_memory_barrier_implementation says that ICC's `__memory_barrier()` is just a compiler barrier.

Comment: Or do you mean combining the effect of a compiler barrier with the x86 memory model, since ICC can only target x86?  (Rather than portably doing just a compiler barrier).  Then yes, as far as inter-thread ordering, that is `atomic_thread_fence(mo_acq_rel)` - no asm instructions on x86, but takes instructions on weakly-ordered ISAs.